# Child context undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, react-context

In the following code I can access a context at the parent and then it's undefined in a child.  It works locally with simple FC setups, but fails downstream in a class component.

```
const HookDialog = () => {

    const { data, setData } = useDialog(1);  // I work fine

    return (
        <DialogHook>
            <DialogContent>
                <h1>Value: {data}</h1>
            </DialogContent>
            <Footer>
                <FooterButton name="positive">Positive</FooterButton>
            </Footer>
        </DialogHook>
    );
}
```

```
export const FooterButton: React.FC<FooterButtonProps> = (
    {
        children,
        name,
        className,
        ...props
    }) => {
        const dialogHook = useDialog();  // I'm undefined!

        return(
            <Button {...props} className={cssNames} ...>
                {children}
            </Button>
        );
}
```

```
export const DialogProvider = props => {
    const [dialog, setDialog] = useState<ReactElement<typeof Dialog>>();
    const [data, setData] = useState<any>();

    return (
      <DialogContextHook.Provider value={{ dialog, setDialog, data, setData }} {...props} >
        {props.children}
        {dialog}
      </DialogContextHook.Provider>
    )
  }
```

```
type CloseEvent = (source: string, data:any) => void;
interface useDialog extends DialogContextHook {
    close: (source: string) => void;
}

export const useDialog = (
    initialValue?: any,
    onClose?: CloseEvent) => {
    const context = useContext(DialogContextHook);
  
    if (!context) {
      throw new Error('useDialog must be used within a DialogProvider');
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        context.setData(initialValue);
    },[])

    const close = (source: string) => {
        context.setDialog(undefined);
        onClose?.(source, context.data);
    }
    
    return { ...context, close };
  }
```

```
                    <DialogProvider>
                        <VOITable/>
                    </DialogProvider>
```

### Update

I recreated `FooterButton` in the downstream project and the same code works, just not when imported.

Comment: can we see where you use DialogProvider, and can we look at `useDialog`?

Comment: Added the two code blocks.  I'm mid-blind-dart in `useDialog` so it's not exactly what I've been running, but close.  `HookDialog` is create _in_ `VOITable`.

Comment: Just double checked, cuz I didn't really believe it.  But verbatim code copy `FooterButton` in the downstream project works.  The documentation for this one is gonna be fun, but I'm pretty close to punting.

Comment: The fact that `useDialog` cant' return `undefined` at all (it will throw at most) make me think is an issue with the code importing another function, not the one you expect. Can you verify you don't have any webpack magic or typescript alias and the like that may import a different function instead?

Comment: Yes, it does throw; I switched to `useContext` just to eliminate moving parts and it is undefined.  The upstream component library is as close to vanilla webpack as it comes.  The downstream is 3k lines of custom zero-ownership Gulp.  But I think we're in agreement it's some very obscure build/import thing.

Getting rid of the current build system is on my list, but that's such a big project we can't even get anyone to agree on who will pay for it, lol.